# Error building a content type in SP 2007

Tags: content-type, event-handlers

I have an event handler that catches an ItemAdding event and changes the content type on the fly.  This is my code to build the content type:

```
SPContentType baseContentType = web.AvailableContentTypes["Folder"];
SPContentType type = new SPContentType(baseContentType, web.ContentTypes, "Custom Folder");

// Add fields to new content type
AddField(ref type, "User", "Owner");
AddField(ref type, "DateTime", "Date");
AddField(ref type, "Text", "Description");
AddField(ref type, "Text", "Justification");
AddField(ref type, "User", "Users");

list.ContentTypes.Add(type);
list.Update();
```

..
snip
..

```
void AddField(ref SPContentType contentType, string fieldType, string fieldName)
    {
        SPField field = new SPField(contentType.Fields, fieldType, fieldName);
        if (fieldName.Equals("Users"))
            ((SPFieldUser)field).AllowMultipleValues = true;
        SPFieldLink fieldLink = new SPFieldLink(field);
        contentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLink);  // Exception thrown here
        contentType.Update();
    }
```

On the line:
    contentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLink);,

I'm getting an ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null.  Parameter name: g

Does anyone know what this means or can see what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means your `SPField field = new ...` returned null, as that's what you're trying to pass it into the `new SPFieldLink`.

If you're trying to create new fields, I strongly recommend using `SPFieldCollection.Add()` (so, in your example, contentType.Fields.Add()) this will return the internal name of the field just added, so you need to retrieve it again field `contentType.Fields` and then add it to the FieldLink Collection.

By the way, can you make sure you're not executing this code every time an item is added (you said you're building an event receiver) - as this will start to throw all sorts of errors as soon as you upload your second item.

Comment: So, instead of the line SPFieldLink fieldLink = new SpFieldLink(field), I do: contentType.Fields.Add(field); and then something like SPFieldLink fieldLink = contentType.Fields[contentType.Fields.Count-1]; ?

Comment: I'm doing this instead now: contentType.Fields.Add(field);
            SPFieldLink fieldLink = new SPFieldLink(contentType.Fields[fieldName]);, but now i get the following exception: "This functionality is unavailable for field collections not associated with a list."

Comment: You'll have to call Update() on the new field to commit it to the content database before you attempt to add a fieldlink to it to the content type, like here: http://pastebin.com/RZu901kW

Comment: Thanks James - still getting the same exception.  Should I be doing this in ItemAdded or ItemAdding?  Actually, the exception gets thrown on field.Update()  Sorry - it's not the same.  It's an SPException: This functionality is unavailable for FIELDS not associated with a list

Comment: If you're doing this on either, you'll be trying to create the same fields and add them to the same content type each time you try to add files to the library. Are you deleting the library every time you try this?

Comment: No, I'm not deleting the library.  I do a check in code to see if the content type already exists before attempting to recreate it

Comment: And the fields, too, yeah?

Comment: No.. but if the content type isn't created, then the fields should be created fresh I would think, since they're only associated with the content type that was never created.  (am I wrong?)

Comment: Exactly, create the fields before the content type. But only create the field if it doesn't exist. Also, I think we both got confused - create the field at Site Collection Level first (SPSite.RootWeb.ContentTypes), it's easier to add to the content type that way.

Comment: Did you mean SPSite.RootWeb.Fields?

Comment: So, I create the fields before adding them to the content type?  I'm not sure I see how that's different than creating the content type and then adding the fields one by one

Comment: The field needs to be persisted to the database (with `Update()`) before you can add it to the content type, otherwise the "Add" method for the content type will try to load details for an SPField that doesn't yet exist in the content database, hence your SPException.

Comment: Thanks James.  I'm going to try it the way this guy does it: http://www.jppinto.com/2010/07/create-custom-columns-and-content-types-in-sharepoint-2007-moss-using-c/  Cheers!

Comment: No worries - That's a good post, demonstrates what I was meaning.